# Create dynamically table with different col numbers on each row in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have template forms that the user can fill with data. The forms are represented as tables. In the database the data for each filled template form is saved with RowNum and ColNum so I can recreate the form on demand. The problem is that for one form the columns on the different rows vary. Just to make it clear here is a simple example :

[image: Example Table]

Here the firs row is empty, the second has one column which display a picture and then follows 4 rows with two columns.

This is just an example. Te set up will vary from form to form. Now I collect the data like this:

```
List<object> dummyData = new List<object>()
            {
                new  {Row = 1, Col = 1, IsRequired = true, QuestionText = "Yes?", FieldValue = "int"},
                new  {Row = 1, Col = 2, IsRequired = true, QuestionText = "Yes?", FieldValue = "int"},
                new  {Row = 2, Col = 1, IsRequired = true, QuestionText = "No?", FieldValue = "string"},
                new  {Row = 3, Col = 1, IsRequired = false, QuestionText = "No?", FieldValue = "string"}
            };
ViewBag.Header = dummyData;
```

This is just for testing but the real data will look much like this. So as you can see the first and the second record are for the same row but right now I can't think of a way to represent the data correctly in the view.

Right now I'm hard coding everything by using `<td colspan="2">` where I know I don't need two columns and yet no solution about how to add extra column instead of a new row when I have situation like this from the exmaple:

```
new  {Row = 1, Col = 1, IsRequired = true, QuestionText = "Yes?", FieldValue = "int"},
                new  {Row = 1, Col = 2, IsRequired = true, QuestionText = "Yes?", FieldValue = "int"},
```

Maybe I need a totally different approach, right now I think of some way using `foreach` and some nested logic there but can't think anything that's working right now.

P.S

Right now all I do in the view is :

```
@{
              foreach (var item in ViewBag.Header)
              {

                  <tr><td>item.QuestionText</td><td>item.FieldValue</td></tr>

              }
           }
```

Comment: Is there a finite number of different form configurations, or form structure is completely open to take any configuration, perhaps made up by the user at run time? Could you isolate several form configurations as different templates and then save just template name in the database?

Comment: In fact maybe it will be some finite number of templates, it's not clear yet. Most likely there will be max 2 columns per row, but first - you never know what the will change after x months and also - I've been thinking and i think that even If I know that there are 1 or 2 columns it's not that big of e help, because what's the difference if it's 2 or 3...

Comment: Is your data structure locked-in, i.e. legacy data, or this structure is what you came up with in order to support dynamic form structures?

Comment: Both - it's the best we could think of and that's the reason why I stick to it.